# angular filter with group by date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am tracking how many times people click a social button in my app. I would like to only give them credit for one click per day. I currently filter the clicks by social platform but I can not figure out how to group by day and only give them a count of 1 per day. below is my current code:

Controller:

```
Data.get('stats/'+$scope.uid).then(function(data){
    $scope.stats = data.data;

    // determine if the user has any stats
    $scope.hasStats = $scope.stats.length;

    $scope.topUsersObjects = $filter('filter')($scope.stats, { 
        action: "completed" 
    });
    $scope.facebookObjects = $filter('filter')($scope.stats, { 
        platform: "facebook", 
        action: "completed" 
    });
    $scope.twitterObjects = $filter('filter')($scope.stats, { 
        platform: "twitter", 
        action: "completed" 
    });
    $scope.facebookClickedObjects = $filter('filter')($scope.stats, { 
        platform: "facebook", 
        action: "clicked" 
    });
    $scope.twitterClickedObjects = $filter('filter')($scope.stats, { 
        platform: "twitter", 
        action: "clicked" 
    });

    $scope.labels = ["Facebook", "Twitter", "Clicked"];

    var totalClicked = $scope.facebookClickedObjects.length + $scope.twitterClickedObjects.length;
    $scope.data = [$scope.facebookObjects.length, $scope.twitterClickedObjects.length, totalClicked];
});
```

UPDATE (sample $scope.stats):

```
Object

action:"clicked ls"
guid:"1200041"
id:"52"
platform:"facebook"
timeclicked:"2015-10-12 21:46:26"
uid:"44043077e53d"
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

FINAL UPDATED ANSWER:

Thank you @William-b your answer worked however, I ended up doing like this. Please let me know if this is not a good approach. thank you to everyone for the help.

```
// facebook group by days, completed
$scope.facebookGroupByDay = _.groupBy($scope.facebookObjects, function(item) {
    return item.timeclicked.substring(0,10);
});

// get the number of days with a completed post
$scope.fbCount = Object.keys($scope.facebookGroupByDay);

 // twitter group by days, clicked 
 $scope.twitterGroupByDay = _.groupBy($scope.twitterClickedObjects, function(item) {
     return item.timeclicked.substring(0,10);
 });

 // get the number of days with a clicked tweet
 $scope.twCount = Object.keys($scope.twitterGroupByDay);
```

Comment: What's the json schema for `$scope.stats`?  I don't see a date anywhere in your example

Comment: @DanielGimenez please see update for an example of the $scope.stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to `reduce` an array of clicks to a count of clicks-by-day.

```
var days = {}; // let's keep track of days clicked here during the reduction

var clicksByDay = $scope.stats.reduce(function (clickCount, stat) {
  var day = stat.timeclicked.split(' ')[0];
  if (!days[day]) {
    // we didnt count this day yet
    clickCount++;
    days[day] = true; // mark this day as counted
  }
  return clickCount;
}, 0);
```

if $scope.stats looks like this:

```
[ 
  { timeclicked: '2015-10-12 12:34:56' },  
  { timeclicked: '2015-10-12 21:46:26'},  
  { timeclicked: '2015-10-13 21:46:26' }  
]
```

then `clicksByDay` will be 2 in this case.

P.S. There is nothing stopping you from defining your own angular filter for this type of reduction if it is needed throughout the templates of multiple controllers.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: please see my edit to my post under FINAL UPDATE ANSWER. Thank you